# Jest cover catch blocks

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I've a simple method in typescript which looks like this

```
async create(user: User): Promise<User> {
    try {
      return await this.userRepository.save(user);
    } catch (exp) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Failed to save user');
    }
}
```

My goal is to reach 100% code coverage for this function. Testing the try block work's fine. But I can't get coverage for the catch block in Istanbul using Jest. My test for the catch block looks like this:

```
it('should throw an error when user is invalid', async () => {
  const invalidUser = new User();
  try {
    await service.create(invalidUser);
  } catch (exp) {
    expect(exp).toBeInstanceOf(BadRequestException);
  }
});
```

As I said Istanbul dosen't show the catch block as tested. What should I do to reach 100% coverage for this method?

Comment: What's invalid about that user?

Comment: The attributes like email, names, etc. are empty. So the repository should throw an SQL exception

Comment: Are you actually using a real repository at that point? It looks more like a unit test. Please give a [mre].

Comment: The first code snippet is using a real repository and the second snippet uses a mock of it

Comment: Isn't the second snippet *testing* the first snippet? Can you show the test double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you shouldn't use try/catch in a test fn. Since you're using async/await try using [`.rejects.toThrow()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects):

```
it('should throw a BadRequestException, when user is invalid', async () => {
  const invalidUser = new User();
  
  await expect(service.create(invalidUser)).rejects.toThrow(BadRequestException);
});
```

If not asserting a rejected promise you can use [`.toThrow()` or `toThrowError()`](http://.toThrowError(DisgustingFlavorError);) instead:

```
it('should throw a BadRequestException, when user is invalid', () => {
  const invalidUser = new User();
  
  expect(service.create(invalidUser)).toThrowError(BadRequestException);
});
```